# MutationObserver not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

**TL;DR: For some reason MutationObserver do not fire at all on my page. The same console snippet works on other pages but just not on my own running on localhost.**

---

I am working in a pretty much standard react SPA built with webpack running on localhost.

Now I am trying to use https://github.com/KingSora/OverlayScrollbars on my page and they are mostly working fine, they just did not seem to detect content changes automatically.
Through a bit of debugging I noticed that the MutationObserver used interally did not fire at all.

Then I started investigating this a bit more and used this snippet on my page:

```js
let obs = new MutationObserver(changes => console.log('changes:', changes));
obs.observe($0, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
});
```

However, no matter how I modified the node ($0) or any other child nodes, the observer did not fire at all.
**Using the same snippet on other pages was working totally fine though!**

Right now I have no idea at all how this could happen so any help or even just ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Ok classic case of "did you try restarting your computer" - or in this case Chrome.

Once I relaunched chrome, they very same snippet started working (just opening a new tab of the page was not enough - I had to completely restart Chrome).

So I guess some issue caused a bug in Chrome and broke the observers on my page so I hope it will continue working just fine now :-/

Comment: This just what happened to me. Restarting the browser fix up the observer

Comment: There is a Chrome bug reported with this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1343214&q=MutationObserver&can=2